# ViewDidLoad not called on custom objects in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I finally made the switch to Storyboards and i am having issues loading custom controllers which was pretty easy to do when using interface builder.

I have **ViewControllerOne**  with two components: A **UIView** and **UITableView** as the subview.

I want the **UITableView** to be controlled by a custom tableview controller. If this was Interface builder i would have dropped a tableview controller onto the XIB, linked to the custom controller and made the connections and it would have been done.

Using storyboard, i don’t believe its possible to drop a **UIViewController/UITableViewController** onto a scene which already has a view controller, i relied on Objects to achieve this.

So i added a Object onto the scene and linked it to my custom tableview controller. I set up delegate/date source for my **UITableView** to point to the custom controller. I finally connected the UITableViews outlet to the custom controller.

When i compile this, the custom controllers delegate (for the table view) gets called but the viewDidLoad is never called.

The only way i can invoke viewDidLoad is if i move the UITableView out of ViewControllerOne. My understanding was that even though there is one view controller for a scene i can still manipulate the subviews using custom controllers.

Am i misunderstanding something or is there is a solution for this ?

Some screenshots
[image: TableView]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of magic in that. Call `self.view` from awakeFromNib and flow will back to the rails

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // here comes the magic - call self.view and view will load as expected
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib %@", self.view)
}
```

you can call it from initWithNibName:bundle:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"awakeFromNib %@", self.view);
    }
    return self;
}
```

the point is to call self.view because apparently something is done inside.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly:

1 Open the storyboard and navigate to the table view controller that you would like to be of your custom type.

2 Click on the identity inspector in the right hand side panel.

3 Set the class to what it should be.

Comment: I have already done that. The class is being called but viewDidLoad is never called.

Comment: And "initial scene" is selected in the attributes inspector?